# Creating new dataset with averages in R

Tags: r, average

I currently have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to create a new dataset of the average rate for each Jurisdiction. It would look something like this:

[image]

Do I need to use a subset option or do I need convert this table from long to wide? I'm a bit lost on the code I need to write to make this work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Hi, really sorry about that. Could you teach me how the proper way to add the 'dput(head(x))' output? When I copy paste it, it says the code is improperly formatted and wont let me submit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely something like this:

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Jurisdiction) %>%
  summarize(
    Years = paste(range(2021:2025), collapse = "-"),
    across(starts_with("rate"), mean)
  )
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much! Just so I fully understand this, what exactly is R doing for the `...across(starts_with("rate"), mean)`

Is it just looking for the rate variables and taking their mean?

Comment: It calculates `mean` for each of the columns that are found with `starts_with("rate")`, something I inferred from looking at the data. It may be read as *"calculate the mean across these columns"*. In this case, it is not renaming them, though I think you can do `across(starts_with("rate"), mean, .names = "avg{.col}")` to get exactly the names you were expecting.

Comment: Ultimately, whenever I see an operation being calculated identically on different columns, I look for a mechanism using `across` (in dplyr pipes) or `lapply` or similar (base R, `data.table`, etc).

Comment: Understood, thank you so much. I appreciate your help and apologize for the trouble!